# python Regex help needed!! One Letter followed by 3 numbers. If found, then delete the entire row in a dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im a Python Newbie.
I would like to find in a column of 30,000 comments when a letter followed by 3 numbers are given.
Such as q100 or n404.

-It will always be in lower case.
-There cant be a space between any of them, a complete word.
-It could be at the beginning of a sentence.

-If this is found the row must be deleted.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.contains` here:

```py
df_out = df[df["comments"].str.contains(r'\b[a-z][0-9]{3}\b', regex=True) == False]
```

The above logic will retain any row *not* containing the code you described.